# How do you convert a customized ubuntu installation into a distro?

Tags: custom-distributions

I've been thinking of making a Linux distro (just a hobby, won't be big and professional like Ubuntu) for some fun and gaining knowledge. I'm thinking of starting small and basing it off Ubuntu with the Mate Desktop Environment (which I will highly customize). I will also make my own theme which I will draw from scratch (windows borders, background set, icons, mouse, menu bars, buttons etc...

It will only include programs in the "program launcher/start menu" that I have made myself with the mono framework except for maybe the Ubuntu software centre. I've heard Linux mint or Ubuntu comes with a live usb maker that converts your customized Ubuntu/Linux mint into a distro or something but I don't know if that's the proper way to make a distro or if it exists/is what I think it is.

Anyway any help on how to convert a modified version of Ubuntu on my computer into an actual distro that I can upload online for people to download and install onto their computer would be very useful. Does a program that does this automatically for you exist? Does it simply make an iso image or is the process more complicated?

Comment: Do you know linux from scratch?

Comment: Try [Relinux](http://www.howtoforge.com/creating-your-own-distributable-ubuntu-dvd-relinux). I have not used it, so I cannot comment on how well it works.

Answer (score 3):

Personally, after making a number of custom iso over the years, I think the debian live scripts are best.

Yes it takes a while to look through the documentation, but in doing so you will learn the steps involved.

Once you learn the process, the scripts automate changes and it is rather trivial to make modifications.

See: http://live.debian.net/manual/stable/html/live-manual.en.html

The debian live scripts are in the ubuntu repositories.

http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/live-build

See also

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomizationFromScratch